# Variable expansion in Makefile

Tags: makefile

It's part of code in a makefile, there are two $$ to expand variable CONTINUE,why? Are there any special meaning?

```
read -r -p "Overwrite your existing default nginx configuration? [y/N] " CONTINUE; 
    if [ "$$CONTINUE" == "y" ] || [ "$$CONTINUE" == "Y" ]; then 
        echo "y"
    else 
        echo "n"
    fi
```

Comment: I'm guessing you really found this in a Makefile, where `$var` will expand the **make** variable named var, and `$$var` will expand the **shell** variable named var. Outside of this context, it's broken.

Comment: yes， it's used in makefile，but how to I didn't understand you @geirha

Comment: Then don't claim it's in a bash script.

Comment: It's certainly not a `script#` either way!

Answer (score 1):

$$ is (simply put) escaping in a Makefile because $-Vars also exists there.
To use the variable for bash (which also needs $var) you have to write $$

pre edit (topic changes from "script" to "makefile")

Does this script even work?

```
# ./test.sh
Overwrite your existing default nginx configuration? [y/N] y
n
```

Change it to a single $.

$$ expands to the PID of the executing bash shell

> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

[Bash ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)